# how to install Interceptor at Postman MAC app?

Tags: interceptor, postman

I followed the following steps:

1 Install Postman from the Chrome Web Store (if you don't have it already!)

2 Install the Interceptor extension.

3 Open Postman.

4 Click on the Interceptor icon in the toolbar and switch the toggle to “on”

5 Browse your app or your website and monitor the requests stream in.

I see the Interceptor at the Chrome Postman, however I cant install it at MAC app. I also tried restarting my computer after the install but it dint work.
I have latest version of CHrome and Postman.
Postman: Version 4.7.0 (4.7.0)
Chrome: Version 53.0.2785.

Is there any other step need for MAC app Postman?

Answer (score 1):

Postman has made it easy to install Interceptor in the native app. First, check if you are in the latest version of the app (Settings > About). If yes, then click on "Start lesson" and that will guide you get the "Interceptor connected"

[image: Interceptor]

Read more: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/interceptor/#installing-interceptor

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Mac native app but Linux native app (v.4.9.3) can use cookies only when **Google Chrome is started** (even if it has Interceptor disabled).